# One class for math vectors of arbitrary dimension

Tags: java, math, vectormath

I want to write a class for mathematical Vectors (holding real numbers). I figured that Vector operations are pretty much the same regardeless of the dimension of the vector, so instead of writing classes like `Vector2D`, `Vector3D`, `Vector4D`, ... I just want to write a `Vector` class.

Now the problem is that I can't multiply a 2D vector with a 4D one, so I thought about a field `dimension`. But now I had to check it for every operation so I asked myself if I can do better than that. This is were generics came to my mind. But then again I have to do something like `Vector<? extends Dimension>`, where `Dimension` is simply a base class of `Dimension.One`, `Dimension.Two` and so on, which means, I have to write a `Dimension` class for every dimension I want to use vectos in.

So my question:

Is there a way of writing one class for vectors of arbitrary dimension without having to check the dimension at runtime?

Comment: I updated my answer with a working implementation. It's probably overkill, but it shows how it could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is that you can't have both. Either you use the type system to ensure correct dimensionality, and then you end up with a proliferation of explicit types (generics won't help you), or you use state to track the dimensions and perform dynamic checks every time you perform an operation.
Since the "dimension" of a vector is how many elements it holds, this will be represented somehow in the underlying data structure. For example if you use a list to store the values in the vector, the list knows how many elements it contains. So doing a simple runtime check is cheap and you can throw an exception when dimensions don't match. That solution is much more flexible and easy to program with than a type based solution.

Comment: +1 for "cheap...[and]...easy to program."  There's real value in this.

Comment: I thought so but hoped that I simply missed something.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed in the `Dimension` class a method that performs the check and throws a `Runtime Exception` if the vectors are incompatible.  Then have every method in `Dimension` invoke this method.  Now the code that *uses* the `Dimension` class won't be littered with checks.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Vector class with some interesting generics

```
public static class Vector<V extends Vector<V>>{
    protected double[] components;
    public final int dimensions;
    private Class<V> klass;

    protected Vector(int d, Class<V> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
        this.components = new double[d];
    }

    public double get(int x) { return components[x] }
    protected void set(int x, double d) { components[x] = d }

    public V clone() {
        try {
            V c = klass.newInstance();
            c.components = this.components.clone();
            return c;
        }
        catch(InstantiationException e1) {}
        catch(IllegalAccessException e2) {}
        return null;
    }

    public V add(V that) {
        V sum = this.clone();
        for(int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
            sum.components[i] += that.components[i];
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Then derive each case:

```
public static class Vector2D extends Vector<Vector2D>{
    public Vector2D() { 
        super(2, Vector2D.class);
    }
    public Vector2D(double x, double y) { 
        this();
        set(0, x);
        set(1, y);
    }
}
public static class Vector3D extends Vector<Vector3D>{
    public Vector3D() { 
        super(3, Vector3D.class);
    }
    public Vector3D(double x, double y, double z) { 
        this();
        set(0, x);
        set(1, y);
        set(2, z);
    }
}
public static class Vector4D extends Vector<Vector4D>{
    public Vector4D() { 
        super(4, Vector4D.class);
    }
    public Vector4D(double w, double x, double y, double z) { 
        this();
        set(0, w);
        set(1, x);
        set(2, y);
        set(3, z);
    }
}
```

After all, there are special cases - for instance, a cross product only exists in 3 and 7 dimensions. Having an implementation for each solves this.

Comment: Unfortunately OP would still have to test dimensionality for each method at runtime.

Comment: @Howard: Not true. The OP would use instances of `Vector3D`, which is guaranteed to have a dimensionality of three. The problem comes when trying to implement a Vector.add method.

Comment: I had some similar ideas but still I had to write classes for each dimension.

Answer (score 0):

To make clear why I wanted to use generics (it works which is why I'm posting it as an answer):

Dimension.java:

```
public class Dimension {
    class ONE extends Dimension {}
    class TWO extends Dimension {}
    class THREE extends Dimension {}
    // [...]
}
```

Vector.java:

```
public class Vector<D extends Dimension> {
    private double[] elements;

    public Vector(double _elmts) {
        elements = _elmts;
    }

    public void add(Vector<D> v) { /*...*/ }
    public void subtract(Vector<D> v) { /*...*/ }
}
```

But as mentioned in my Question, I have to create several classes, which is what I wanted to prevent in the first place. Also it's rather ugly. And there's no way to make sure `elements` has the right dimension other than trusting the user.

I guess it's pretty similar to Eric's answer.

Comment: What you're doing in the Dimension class is basically what Java does for you automatically when you define an enum class. But whatever you do there, someone will always want to use a vector of higher dimension than you allow.

Comment: This version doesn't allow you to implement non-mutating methods